# redirect to page#about using symfony&twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony , I wanna redirect the user to a specific frame in a page
So How can i translate this `<a href="index.html#about"/>` to twig ? I tried `<a href="{{path('pl_index')}}#about"/>` but it doesnt work

Comment: `doesn't work` is pretty much vague. What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in twig you can use {{path('_welcome') }}  and it will send you to your home index, check your route.yml and you can see what are the paths generated by symfony.

for example this is my config.yml:

```
//savabundle config.yml
    sava_inventario_construccion:
        path:     /productos/construccion
        defaults: { _controller: savaInventarioBundle:Inventario:construccion }
    sava_inventario_index:
        path:     /productos/
        defaults: { _controller: savaInventarioBundle:Inventario:index }
```

if i want to generate www.mypage.com/productos/construccion#about link, this is what my html should look like

```
<a href="{{path('sava_inventario_construccion') }}#about"/>
```

you can read more in here
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html

Comment: Thank you , what I tried is "{{path('pl_index")}}"#about .. Now it works Thank's again